# Laravel - Not found exception

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am a newbie php developer using laravel.

I have my **routes.php** defined as such

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('Home.index'); 
});
```

and my **index.blade.php** as such

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h2>All Users</h2>
    <p> {{HTML::link('Home.createuser', 'Add a New User')}} </p>

@stop
```

I have a link from my index.blade.php to a third file called **createuser.blade.php** which is defined as such

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div>
        <legend> Add a User</legend>
    </div>
@stop
```

Both the files , index.blade.php and createuser.blade.php are in the same folder

However, I keep getting the dreaded NotFoundException error whenever i try to access the createuser page from index page.

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA81xF-qsQs&list=PLLJSbW-UxRIzGwfnTT7GKYRfwT7hmeEFd) video.

Someone care to help , please

Thanks

Comment: did you create your route for the create user?

Comment: @LeventeNagy : Nope.. can you please show me how to. I dont understand how to create a route from a second file to a third file . please .. an example will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently just created a route for the index

if you would like to create users you will need to specify that too.

like this

`// returns index view for user`s

```
  Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('Home.index'); 
    });
// create user

Route::get('user/create', function()
    {
        // return the user create view from views/home folder
        return View::make('Home.createuser'); 
    });
```

and now if you browse yoursite.com/user/create you get the create user view

hope its clear

but for more better understanding

Laravel views video tutorial: [laravel views](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is51MnJ-jb8)

Laravel routes video tutorial: [laravel routes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umRGurttZJo)

Comment: Hi Levente.. I made an edit to the post a little bit ago. I linked a youtube video that i was trying to follow. In that video, the tutor does not have any routes to the new view , yet it is still working for him . Can you please explain why ? Here is the link again : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA81xF-qsQs&list=PLLJSbW-UxRIzGwfnTT7GKYRfwT7hmeEFd

Comment: whatch the video carefuly from 15:40 you cleary see he creates a route for the create view if i did not convince you

Comment: ah .. sorry i missed that part.. i am going to mark your answer as the correct answer. Thank you so much for your time and patience- G

Comment: no problem, no need to be sorry, sometimes this happens to all of us, happy to help